# What would happen if the output leads of a multi-phase transformer were shorted together?

Tags: transformer

Just what the question states, and there isn't any design rationale behind the question.

I just opened up a dead CFL (6 tubes; 3-pairs), and it looks to have an itsy little transformer within. This transformer has super-fine wires in the winding with, what looks like, a large number of coils. The output appears to come in 3-pairs of wires - probably 3-phase HV - one for each pair of tubes.

Anyway, I'm curious what would happen if the hot-lead of each phase were shorted together; the same with the cold-leads.

[image]

Thus I would be binding the output wires as ABC, and A'B'C' to form a common output.

My guess is the transformer (if that's what it is) would heat up, and have a reduced life-span.

Comment: Try it and tell us!!! we are also interested to know.Last time I tried such transformer shorting, I ended up with some buzzing sound and a really really hot ............core ;)

Comment: @perilbrain Yes, and after he tries that he should try sticking a fork in a plugin. I've always wondered what that'd do.  (Sarcasm for the unaware. I wouldn't try this without being extremely safe about the process)

Comment: @Earlz:- thats a good idea too!!!

Comment: :P 
@Earlz: does 'this' refer to shorting the output leads, or to sticking a fork in a plug-socket?

p.s. I get your point

Comment: one phase in implies one thphase out. regardless, it will get hot. the magic smoke may even come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one else has stated it explicitly, I will: The power supply inside a CFL is a **non-isolated** supply, and the tiny transformer you see is **not** connected directly to the mains.

Also, any transformer in which all of the windings share the same magnetic path is "single phase", not three-phase. There are 3-phase transformers, but they have three distinct magnetic paths inside.

The transformer is actually part of a high-frequency (typically 10s of kHz) oscillator that produces the various voltages needed to drive the lamp tube. One or more of the windings is driven by a transistor or two, one or more is used for feeback to make the transistor oscillate, and one or more is used to drive the tube itself.

There are two ways you can connect multiple windings on the same transformer together:

1. You can connect them in series, which adds their voltages. The current is limited to the rating of the lowest-rated individual winding.
2. You can connect them in parallel, as long as two criteria are met. First, they need to have the same number of turns, and second, they need to be connected in phase. If either of these is violated, then excessive current will flow and the transformer (and/or its drive circuit) will likely be damaged.

Comment: Dave - you may wish to note (as I know you know) that where they provide N windings, if they are the same then they have probably done it for isolation / level differences. eg in this case to get filament drives at different HV potentials.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Maybe. I have seen CFLs where the two filaments were connected in series, with a PTC thermistor in between that "opens up" after a time delay. In other words, one winding created both the HV and the filament drive. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of use / topology

- Joining together wires
  that should remain asunder
  will may well result in sparks
  and could result in thunder.

It is unlikely that the inverter is a 3 phase one.
 It is very likely that it is single phase.

It would be helpful if you stated the number of tubes and wires more clearly - what you have said could mean several things (or my brain is not working properly)(always possible).

You say "each pair of tubes".
 This implies at least 4 tubes, with them being arranged ion pairs.

You say "3 pairs of wires" impling (or in fact indicating) 6 wires.

"3 phase HV for each pair of tubes requires at least 1.5 wires per tube - but you could mean 3 wires per tube, or two, or ... .

**HOWEVER**

Shorting together 2 wires from connected windings on a CFL would indeed result in heating up - usually with destruction of one of the wires and/or death of the whole CFL, probably in the 0.02 to 5 second range (0.016 to 5 seconds in USA and selected other places).

It is possible that they are using filaments in the tubes - in which case a pair of wires would both convey filament low voltage and act as a path for the high voltage to one end of the tube.

It is also possible that the two wires in a pair go to opposite ends of the same tube and provide the HV excitation to the tube.

Regardless of use / topology - joining wires together that should remain asunder  may result in sparks and, just possibly, thunder.

---

It's been a while since I pulled any dead CFLs apart.
 I just went and had a dig through my daed CFL collection (every workshop should have one) to refresh my memory re typical practice.

A CFL is essentially a conventional fluorescent tube writ small and folded, with an electronic "ballast" to start the tube with high voltage and then provide the correct (much lower) voltage required to operate it at its rated power.

I dismantled a coild tube bulb - which is essentially a single 2 ended glass tube, and a 3 straight loop tube which I expected to consist of 3 separate loops. It didn't. The loops are combined by bridging tubes so that it only has two electrical end amongst its 6 apparent mechanical ends - it's a single tube for the internal 'gas', and electrically.

In my case, and probably in most tubes that are exopected to have good lifetimes, there is a heater/filament at each electrical end of the tube and HV is fed to each end along the heater wire. So, each 2 ended tube has 2 wires per end.
 shorting these two wires together would stop the heater heating and would quite possibly create an informal external heater using the usually rather fine wiring.

Shorting two wires together from each end of a tube would result in the inverter / ballast having an [apoplectic fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoplexy), which would quite possibly be fatal for it. worst case it could also be fatal for the person doing the shorting if power was applied at the time.

---

**Health & Safety notice:**

Note that CFL tubes contain a small amount of mercury. If you don't eat the tubes after use and avoid breaking them while thy are operating and breathing the fumes and if you wash your hands after breaking one, while all the while refraining from licking your fingers, then odds are that the mercury amount is too small to matter very much. [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) .

Cutting yourself on broken-CFL glass may be a worse than average idea. As well as the mercury there is phosphor which is not intended for internal use.

Comment: The description is updated with an image to express what I'm looking at.